# how I can get all elements of groups when one row has specific value

Tags: r, dataframe

How I can get whole group's element where at least one row has `MODE==2`.

```
 group1     group2      MODE
   1          1          1
   1          1          2
   1          2          1
   1          2          3  
   2          1          1
   2          1          4
   2          2          1
   2          2          2
   2          2          1
   4          1          2
```

output

```
 group1     group2      MODE
   1          1          1
   1          1          2 
   2          2          1
   2          2          2
   2          2          1
   4          1          2
```

all groups whose don't have row with `MODE==2` are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'group1', 'group2', `filter` with `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(group1, group2) %>%
   filter(2 %in% MODE)
```

Or wrap with `any` and `==`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(group1, group2) %>%
   filter(any(MODE == 2))
```